# How to redirect after angular function by mvc action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I want to redirect user after success in angular function by mvc action. here is my controller :

```
   $scope.login = function () {
        debugger;
        authService.login($scope.loginData).then(function (response) {
            debugger;

            $modalInstance.close(true);
            $location.path('/Home');
        },
         function (err) {
             $scope.message = err.error_description;
             $modalInstance.dismiss();
         });
    };
```

but it's not working ?

the dirty way is :

```
<p class="login-success" ng-if="cartable">


                    @Html.ActionLink("ورود به کارتابل", "Index", "Home", null, null)


                    </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you try the vanilla javascript way ?

```
window.location.href="yournewUrlHere";
```